# Encapsulate multiple $(document).ready() into one scope

Tags: jquery, ajax

After days of learning Ajax with different materials, I found that there're multiple
`$(document).ready(function()` in one single html file

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
....
}
$(document).ready(function(){
....
}
$(document).ready(function(){
....
}
...
</script>
```

I tried to integrated them to a single `$(function () {}` scope, but found that some codes not working as intended.

I am fresh to learn jQuery and Ajax, should I leave them that way, could there's a solution out to encapsulate them into one.

Comment: Wrap all function in one `$(document).ready(function(){})`

Comment: There's no inherent reason that combining the code from multiple `ready` callbacks into one would make them stop working, so whatever the problem is, it'll be specific to the code that was where those `....` were in the above.

Comment: There should be no reason to have multiple ready-callbacks declared but sometimes the backend on the server creates javasript-blocks on many parts of the page, then it is sometimes convinient to just wrap them in their own ready-callbacks.